# Reading Partitioned HIVE table in SPARK SQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read the HIVE table has 2 years of data and it is partitioned on day, Reading it through SPARK-SQL takes more than 10 mins even after filter applied for 6 months data.

Any idea how to improve, i have tried with DISTRIBUTE BY clause in Hive QL

Comment: Check your query plan

Comment: Check if partition filters are getting applied.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable partitioning pruning by setting property :

```
spark.sql.hive.metastorePartitionPruning=true
```

This will filter the partitions

Comment: NO its not helping, launching 114588 tasks due to those many dir's